# set a function to always run on a page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm totally new to windows phone development but have been working with unity for a while, my question is how to make a function to always run on a page, like I have a function to increment a value, how do I make it to always run. putting it on the onNavigatedTo function makes it runs just once. it's like what the void Update () function does in unity. is there such code in windows phone 8.1??

Comment: Do you want to call the function after some interval?

Comment: Yes kinda, but after a short interval so it acts like it keeps updating

Comment: You can use DispacherTimer

Answer (score 0):

You can use DispacherTimer

```
private override onNavigatedTo (...)

     {
       DispatcherTimer timer= new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
     timer.Tick +=timer_Tick;
    }
  private async void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        //Do your work here
    }
```